# Jekyll Default index.html not displaying styles

Tags: html, github, jekyll

[Default site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvyCE.png)

The initial default index.html is not showing any style. I have not edited any code inside the folders that Jekyll created. When I try to run it on localhost this is what shows. No styles.

Basically just installed Jekyll on my system, then tried to create a new folder using "jekyll new 'foldername'" then ran "jekyll serve --watch". After that checked my localhost and it will not display the style.

This is the Repo [Github](https://github.com/juscuizon/jekylltest)

Comment: We lack information to provide a decent answer. Can you please show some code or insight about how you host it?

Comment: Or a repository url.

Comment: @juscuizon check your source (CTRL+U) and see if there is a css? and if there is one (at least) click on it to see what's inside it.

Comment: @R.Mazarei This is the css link inside the index.html http://example.com/css/main.css

Comment: @juscuizon what's in this file?

Comment: @R.Mazarei website with css codes hosted by example.com. What I don't get is, why doesn't it display the style. I didn't modify the codes inside the jekyll folders.

Comment: @juscuizon there is nothing [here](http://example.com/css/main.css), you have to change the link to css somewhere in your code. Are you working locally or you've uploaded your code on some domain?

Comment: @R.Mazarei locally. But the thing is all of the installations the same as mine have styles. I don't know why my download and installation of jekyll doesn't display the style. While other users did what I exactly did and their's displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Jekyll to version 3.3.0 and styles now work. But still i didn't know why version 3.2.1 Doesn't display styles.